# Spring boot Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory not show error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, logging

In a spring boot + hibernate app, some changes in the database and JPA has been done, however somethign seems not work well because it throw error to create the hibernate session factory.

But the logs do not show what is wrong.

This is the log error:

```
2019-05-29 15:39:19.166  WARN 8588 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beansConfiguration': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [x/x/guias/config/JpaConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: guiasUnitName] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Sometimes it has fixed find out the error but it should to inform where hibernate crash.

this is the pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId> 
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-client-support-saml</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Eliminado en 03/05/2019 por problema con dependencias anteriores 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

EDIT:

Jpa Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource guiasDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(guiasDataSource);
        emf.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();


        //vendor.setGenerateDdl(false);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("x.x.guias");
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName("guiasUnitName");
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return tm;
    }

    private Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();


        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans",env.getProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"));
        properties.setProperty("show_sql", env.getProperty("show_sql"));
        properties.setProperty("format_sql", env.getProperty("format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource evisadoDatasourceJndi() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/GuiasDS");
    }
}
```

JNDI configuration:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/GuiasDS" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1111:YYYY" username="USER"
    password="XXX"
    maxActive="377"
    initialSize="5"
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
    maxWait="-1"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
    singleton="false" />
```

application.properties:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/guias

##################### Logging ##################
logging.level.x.x=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug
logging.level=TRACE

############################ DATASOURCE LOCAL x############################
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
###############################################################################

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=beans, info, metrics, loggers, heapdump, sessions, configprops, env, health

#App
##hibernate properties
show_sql = true
format_sql = true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

EDIT: 30/05/2019

I resolved this using a no spring boot proyect, so the proyect without spring boot tell where table and entity is wrong. but in spring boot no.

Comment: persistenceUnit is not properly configured in `persistence.xml` or `entityManagerFactory` bean definition

Comment: this always work, so I think it is ok.

Comment: it is okay but error occurs, so it's okay )

Comment: how do you explain that before the database was changed it's works ?

Comment: Please show some configuration. How do you configure the database and JPA?

Comment: @Lucke because your configuration fits a previous DB environment, but doesn't fit the new one

Comment: @AlexSalauyou The database conection is the same. It has to be in the jpa domain classes model. however this do not show where the error is.

Comment: You didn't post the stack trace of the exception. That's where the information you're looking for probably is.